# Windows 10: Pin an item to left side of Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Has anyone figured out how to pin an item to the left side of the start menu? Articles online about this are referencing an older version of 10 where this was possible.

- No matter the size of Start, clicking Pin to Start Menu will create
  another column and pin a tile there
- Cannot drag from right side to
  left, or from anywhere for that matter

Here's how my Start appears, after removing Most Used and Recently Added.
Simply want an app pinned anywhere in the gray area:

[image]

Comment: If you want that functionality.  You have to use StartIsBack++ or Start10 or something like those two programs.

Comment: The silly thing is, it WAS possible..They removed that option when they released the first major public preview a few months ago... Oh Microsoft... why don't you learn?! Everyone, please use the built-in Feedback application and up-vote the Start Menu issue.

Comment: Upvote on uservoice :-) https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/9083197-option-to-pin-apps-or-programs-to-the-left-side-of

Comment: Typical. Microsoft has been removing useful features from its products for years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pin items there but you can have recent apps there and exclude certain apps. Which basically means you can customize it, it's just tedious.

1. Go to Settings > Personalization > Start
2. Turn on "Show Most Used Apps"
3. Start launching apps you want in there. It will hold 6 apps.

[image]

Comment: How do you get the list of recently opened files to show up? For me it shows on some programs but not others.